# Javascript copy to clipboard function messages doesn't work if used twice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code I edited from w3tutorials. When you click on the `Hello World` button, it says `Copied: Welcome Message`. However if you click `John` button, it doesn't say anything. it copies to the clipboard, but doesn't show the "Copied" message.

```js
function myFunction(classID, IDName) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(classID);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + IDName;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="welcome">

  <div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction('welcome', 'Welcome Message')" onmouseout="outFunc()">
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy text
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <input type="text" value="John" id="fname">

  <div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction('fname', 'First Name')" onmouseout="outFunc()">
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy text
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: becuse you have ``id="myTooltip"`` twice in your code

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya So how can I parse the id so it changes the right thing

Comment: you can pass diffrant id as paramiter while calling function and apply that id to that text span

Comment: better to use "T.J. Crowder" solution , just pass clicked object and then query(parse) that span using class exist inside that button object , rather than applying id multiple time

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit, just realized I should have noted you'll need a polyfill for `Element#closest` on older browsers (but it's a simple one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`id`s must be unique.** You probably don't want to use any IDs in this code at all. Instead, put each structure in a `div` so you can relate the elements to each other structurally rather than with IDs (it also eliminates the need for that `<br>`). For instance, with this structure:

```
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" value="Hello World">

  <div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this, 'Welcome Message')" onmouseout="outFunc(this)">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy text
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that `this` is passed into the handler functions (really, we should be using modern event handling, but I'm trying not to change too much in one go). `this` will be the element that function is attached to. Then in the code, it's easy to find the various other elements in that group:

```
function myFunction(button, IDName) {
  var input = button.closest(".group").querySelector("input");
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

  var tooltip = button.querySelector(".tooltiptext");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + IDName;
}

function outFunc(button) {
  var tooltip = button.querySelector(".tooltiptext");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

Then of course, as always, we can factor out common code to utility functions:

```
function myFunction(button, IDName) {
  var input = button.closest(".group").querySelector("input");
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  setTooltipForButton(button, "Copied: " + IDName);
}

function outFunc(button) {
  setTooltipForButton(button, "Copy to clipboard");
}

function setTooltipForButton(button, text) {
  button.querySelector(".tooltiptext").innerHTML = text;
}
```

I should note that that uses [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which is supported by modern browsers but not in some older ones. You can use a polyfill for older browsers to add it, though.

Live Example:

```js
function myFunction(button, IDName) {
  var input = button.closest(".group").querySelector("input");
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  setTooltipForButton(button, "Copied: " + IDName);
}

function outFunc(button) {
  setTooltipForButton(button, "Copy to clipboard");
}

function setTooltipForButton(button, text) {
  button.querySelector(".tooltiptext").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" value="Hello World">

  <div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this, 'Welcome Message')" onmouseout="outFunc(this)">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy text
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">  
  <input type="text" value="John">

  <div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this, 'First Name')" onmouseout="outFunc(this)">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy text
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, if you need the `id`s for something else, it's okay to include them, they just need to be unique on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same ID more than one time.
You can add a counter or a pointer to make the ID unique.

```js
function myFunction(classID, IDName) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(classID);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip-" + classID); //modify here
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + IDName;
}

function outFunc(classID) {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip-" + classID);//modify here
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="welcome">

  <div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction('welcome', 'Welcome Message')" onmouseout="outFunc('welcome')"><!--modify here-->
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip-welcome"><!--modify here-->Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy text
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <input type="text" value="John" id="fname">

  <div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction('fname', 'First Name')" onmouseout="outFunc('welcome')"><!--modify here-->
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip-fname"><!--modify here-->Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy text
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can also generate dinamically the tooltip with append https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: Why not using Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line: `var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");` , when you click the second button, it's the text in the first tooltip that changes because you can't use the same ID twice.

I edited your code to select the tooltip using the class name and replace each tooltip's text whenever the button is clicked.

Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBEJjB